# Is there a way to a list of all cidrs for a GCP VPC like I can with aws_subnet_ids?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html

The AWS provider makes this possible:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "example" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}

data "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids
  id       = each.value
}

output "subnet_cidr_blocks" {
  value = [for s in data.aws_subnet.example : s.cidr_block]
}
```

But is there a way to do this with google_compute_network and google_compute_subnetwork? google_compute_subnetwork supports self_link and google_compute_network has an attribute subnetworks_self_links- I'm just not sure how to connect them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK think i got it

```
data "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
  name = google_compute_network.default-vpc.name
}

data "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetworks" {
  for_each = toset(data.google_compute_network.vpc.subnetworks_self_links)
  self_link       = each.value
}

output "ip-cidr-ranges" {
  value = [for s in data.google_compute_subnetwork.default-vpc-subnetworks : s.ip_cidr_range]
}
```

This seems to work but appreciate if someone can confirm i didnt do something stupid. As of right now I have only *one* subnetwork. havent tested with multiple ones yet